# StackOverFlow Error in WSO2 ESB while reading large xml file

Tags: wso2, esb

I am facing problem while sending an XML request to my rest service which is configured in WSO2. But I am able to send same XML file to my rest service without using WSO2.
Once I am trying to send XML using WSO2 i am getting following error.

ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1844)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3032)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2919)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3059)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2919)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3059)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3059)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2919)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3059)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2919)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3059)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2919)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3059)

Source Code which i am using inside WSO2 ESB is as follow

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TESTAPI" context="/rest">
   <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/createUpdateJRXML">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="createUpdateJRXML" value="Creating JRXML ..">       </property>
     </log>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <http method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:8080/DocumentServer-Web/documentservice/createUpdateJRXML"></http>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
```

Comment: If you provide more details we can help you. What are you using inside esb? put the source here,

Comment: please paste your xml here

Comment: Are you using oracle jdk? if so take a look at http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6976938

Comment: Hi Sajith i am getting this issue in Linux environment which is having jdk6 but in windows environment its working fine.Windows environment also having jdk6.

Comment: I am getting this error only when XML size is big . If I will reduce the XML size i am able to upload XML file with the help of wso2.